# Defining new variable

Tags: java, variables

I'm quite new at programming in Java and I've encountered something I don't really understand:

```
if (Object.getSomething() != null) {
        Long Size= null != Object.getSomething().getSomething2()
            ? Object.Something().getSomething2() : null;
```

I've been looking for the answer but I can't understand this way of defining a new variable, I mean, the '?' and the ': null' are the things I can't understand.

Comment: read about ternary conditional expression

Comment: Some examples of that syntax: https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: This statement (all below the `if`) us useless and could (or better should) be replaces by `Long Size= Object.getSomething().getSomething2()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a simple ternary operation:

```
Object object;
int i = object == null ? 1 : 2;
```

In Java code, it is the same as writing the standard `if-else` statement

```
Object object;
int i;

if (object == null) {
    i = 1;
} else {
    i = 2;
}
```

As you can see, the amount of lines it takes the traditional approach is much more. This is one of the main strengths of ternary operator.

In natural language, ternary operations read as:
"Is `object equals to null`? Then `1` otherwise `2`".

Answer (score 4):

Ternary conditionals take the following form:

`condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

Consider for instance the mathematical `max` function. Using regular conditional statements we could write:

```
int max = 0;
if (a > b) {
  max = a;
} else {
  max = b;
}
```

We can do the exact same thing using a ternary condition:
`max = a > b ? a: b;`

Answer (score 2):

This is a ternary operator in java.
syntax is

```
result = testCondition ? value1 : value2
```

i.e if testcondition is true, put value1 in result, else put value2 in result.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Object.getSomething() != null)
    Long Size= null != Object.getSomething().getSomething2()
        ? Object.Something().getSomething2() : null;
```

This line is equivalent to the following :

```
if (Object.getSomething() != null)
    Long Size = null;
    if (null != Object.getSomething().getSomething2())
        Size = Object.Something().getSomething2();
```

See [this](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) about ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use ternary operator here. Here is simplified version to assign the value to Size:

Long Size= null != object.getSomething() ? 10L : null;

If null != object.getSomething() is true then 10L will be assigned else null will be assigned.